# How to create a puzzle from a pre-existing, fixed data source?

Tags: puzzle-creation

Examples of what I mean:

*Instructions lead puzzlers to a library where the names of donors are inscribed on bricks out front. Along with some piece of information that is given to them on a piece of paper, they are able to find a phrase which is the solution to the puzzle*

*Puzzlers go to a certain wall where ceramic tiles of different colors are irregularly laid out. Along with information that they have brought with them on their phone, they are able to find a one-word solution to the puzzle*

Do you have any tips for these sorts of puzzles? Methods for finding patterns? Pitfalls not to fall into?

Thanks!

Comment: One thing that I'd definitely recommend if time permits, is have some people who aren't a part of the puzzle creation or end search do a test run so you can see what hints or unclear and what types of misconceptions others may have. When creating puzzles since you already know the solution things often seem more obvious than they are to an outsider.

Comment: @gabbo1092 thanks! Yes, we are planning extensive playtesting. This is for an event next July :D